# Can I select an #include path using a script and command line args in an Inno Setup installer?

Tags: command-line-arguments, inno-setup, pascalscript

So the problem arises where I have a number of installations where most everything is the same except of course the files in the install. I have a suite of include files that are different.

So I thought, "Hey, lets simply add a command line argument to specify what file to include." I can get information from the command line argument in the Pascal code.

The problem comes when I try to use the information in the `#include`. The preprocessor seems to know nothing about the Pascal scripting. That makes sense, except that I want it to know. for example, I can't do this:

```
[Files]
#include "{code:GetMyArgument}"
```

or this:

```
[Files]
#include {param:foo|bar}
```

So the question is really: How can I set a `#include` to include a path file that I set in the command line arguments? or some other dynamic method... I can think of one. I just don't like my way: I don't like the idea of moving files around or changing file contents on the fly for this, my/this/these solutions smell, I think. Is there a better way?

I am on version 5.5.6(u) of Inno Setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a preprocessor variable:

```
#include IncludePath
```

And specify its value on compiler's command-line:

```
ISCC.exe Example1.iss /DIncludePath=Other.iss
```

---

Meaning of the [`/D` switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=isppcc):

```
/D<name>[=<value>] Emulate #define public <name> <value>
```

---

If you are using an Inno Setup IDE that does not support setting compiler's command-line arguments (like Inno Script Studio), you can base the included script's filename on some installer's option, like `AppId`, `AppName`, `OutputBaseFilename`, etc.

For example for a name based on the `AppName`, use:

```
#include SetupSetting("AppName") + ".iss"
```

Note that this works only if the `#include` directive, with the call to [`SetupSetting` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=setupsetting), is after the respective `[Setup]` section directive.

---

Yet another option is to reverse the include.

A main `.iss` is project-specific and it includes a shared `.iss`:

Project-specific `.iss`:

```
; Project-specific settings
[Setup]
AppId=id
AppName=name

[Files]  
; Project specific files

; Include shared script
#include "shared.iss"
```

Note that it's perfectly OK, if the sections repeat. So the `shared.iss` can include again both `[Setup]` and `[Files]` sections with other directives and files.

Comment: I get: Undeclaired Identifier: "IncludePath" when I compile.

Comment: You have shown me the problem... I think.. It seems that I have reached the limits of Inno Script Studio. It appears to work on the raw command line. (Thanks)

Comment: @amalgate: Maybe you could try the Visual & Installer (www.visual-installer.com) or RAD & Installer (www.rad-installer.com) tools instead of Inno Script Studio. This command line stuff is fully supported.

Comment: I am actually planning to use the command line, so I am happy. The installer we have is already fairly mature, just making a change to reduce the need for interns. Anyway, thanks for the alternatives, and your solution. It works great. And thanks for the additional details. I regret I only have but one +1 to give.